# How to have a textArea display contents of a file

Tags: java

Ok so I will try to make this as understandable as possible. I have created a simple GUI with an "open" button and a textArea (along with other stuff but that's not important right now). Basically I am creating a method that when I click the Open button it displays the contents of the file in the textArea. I believe 99% of the method I have written is correct but I keep getting a NullPointerException and I don't quite understand why. Hopefully my code will clear up any confusion on what I am asking, I will comment on the line of code where I get the exception. Here is my code:

Application class (Basic setup of my GUI):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Application extends JFrame {

public OutputPanel outPanel = new OutputPanel();
public BarcodePanel barPanel = new BarcodePanel();
public ButtonPanel btnPanel = new ButtonPanel();
public ReferencePanel refPanel = new ReferencePanel();

public Application() {
    super("Book Processor");
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    btnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    outPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    refPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(outPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(refPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}//end constructor

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application frame = new Application();
    frame.setSize(1000,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}//end main

}//end class
```

The next set of code is my ButtonPanel class(this is where I am having an issue) So I have an openFile method, that when I click the button it should display the contents of the file in the textArea. Again I receive a NullPointerException and I do not understand why. Here is the code for this class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{


JButton btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
OutputPanel outPanel = new OutputPanel();
Scanner input;

public ButtonPanel() {
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

add(btnOpen);
btnOpen.addActionListener(handler);

}//end constructor


 /**
  * Method for displaying the file onto the textArea.
  * 
  */
private void openFile() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);


    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    String fileName;

    fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {

            sb.append(input.nextLine()+ "\n");

        }

        outPanel.txtOutput.setText(sb.toString());//my issue is with this line right here

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        input.close();
    }

}//end readFile



private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()== btnOpen) {

            openFile();

        }

    }//end actionPerformed


}//end actionlistener


}//end class
```

Here is my last class, OutputPanel, this class contains the JTextArea:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class OutputPanel extends JPanel{

public JTextArea txtOutput = new JTextArea(20,50);

public OutputPanel() {

    add(txtOutput);

}//end constructor

}//end class
```

How do I get the textArea to display the contents of the file. More importantly why am I getting this exception and what can I do to fix it. Hopefully this makes as much sense as possible, and I really appreciate any and all input from you guys.

Comment: Where is the line who give you NullPointerExeption ?

Comment: I commented on it, its the line that says: outPanel.txtOutput.setText(sb.toString());

Comment: you have check if is outPanel.txtOutput are null or if is sb ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking

Comment: you get nullPointerExeption on what ? sb or outPanel.txtOutput ?

Comment: outPanel.txtOutput is where I get the exception